# How do I make specific edits to the first field of a tsv text file using sed (or awk)?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a long TSV file that looks like this:

```
name1_otherinfo    field2
namess2_otherinfo    field2
names3_otherinfo    field2
etc...
```

I'm trying to clean up the first field by simply removing the letters "*otherinfo", AND adding the words NEW* at the beginning, such that I should get this:

```
NEW_name1    field2
NEW_namess2    field2
NEW_names3    field2
etc...
```

I'm finding sed to be quite overwhelming and I'm not sure where best to look for the specific solution. And I'm not sure how to isolate specifics subtractive substrings using awk. The "_otherinfo" part is the same, but the name is subject to change, so substr seems to not target what I want. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk:

```
awk '{sub(/_otherinfo/, "", $1); print "NEW_"$1 "\t" $2}' file
```

Comment: I think I found something similar. This aught to do it. awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-1)}' file.txt

Comment: *awk '{print substr($1, 1, length($1)-8)}' file.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sed, e.g. this works with GNU sed and your example data:

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]+)_otherinfo/NEW_\1/' file
```

It captures whatever

- is at the linestart (`^`)
- a sequence of character not tab (`[^\t]+`)
- up to but not including the `_otherinfo`

into `\1`, the `_otherinfo` is not captured and therefore discarded in the replacement. The replacement uses `\1` and prepends `NEW_`. Only lines with `_otherinfo` are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} sub(/_otherinfo$/, "", $1) {$1 = "NEW_" $1} 1' file

NEW_name1   field2
NEW_namess2 field2
NEW_names3  field2
```

**Breakup:**

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}          # set input & output field separator as tab
sub(/_otherinfo$/, "", $1)  # remove "_otherinfo" from end of first column
{$1 = "NEW_" $1}            # if sub is success then prefix 1st col with "NEW_"
1                           # default awk action to print each line
```

Comment: To only affect the "otherinfo" lines: `if (sub(/_otherinfo/, "", $1)) {$1 = "NEW_" $1}`

Comment: Can you break it down into what his happening at each statement?

Comment: I've added details explanation.